# Spring Boot and Jboss wildfly setting the context root

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to set the context root of my spring boot application.  I'm deploying my application as a war file to Jboss.
i've tried to set the contextPath of what I'd like my root URL to be when deploying it to JBoss/Wildfly but it seems to get ignored.  Unless I add a jboss-web.xml file setting a contex-root variable, my deployment url is always based on the war file name:

e.g. :  myapp.war always deploys as :  localhost:8080/myapp unless I use jboss-web.  I've tried setting the contextPath in the server.properties file and it doesn't seem to work.

My question is should I be able to?   I'm using the latest Spring Boot.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In other words, add your `jboss-web.xml`

file in this directory : `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`

Content of your jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
        <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Answer (score 10):

All of the `server.*` properties that Spring Boot supports only apply to the configuration of the embedded servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty, or Undertow). If you're deploying your Spring Boot app to a standalone server then you'll need to configure that server using whatever mechanisms it provides.