# How to access a spring boot application deployed in JBoss AS 7?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, jboss

I'm new to spring mvc and I've followed the [starter guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) to import the `hello web` application (`Service Web Content` at the Spring Tool Suite). It works great as a standalone application using embedded Tomcat servlet.

I then proceeded to package the application [as a war](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging). Actual steps taken are as following:

1. Make Application class extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` and add a SpringApplicationBuilder configure method.
2. Set embedded tomcat to `provided`.
3. Set Maven packaging to `war`.

However after exporting & deploying gs-serving-web-content-initial.war to jboss AS 7 I couldn't find a way to access the app!

Both `http://localhost:8080/greeting` and `http://localhost:8080/gs-serving-web-content-initial/greeting` gives the same `404 The requested resource (/greeting) is not available.`. (Another war built before with structs is tested to work fine on the same jboss)

Adding a [jboss-web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411668/spring-boot-and-jboss-wildfly-setting-the-context-root) doesn't work either. So what am I missing?

update 20151217:

Related JBoss log appended as below. A warning (JBAS011006) shows when deploying the war but it seems to be [normal for spring wars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786685/spring3-2-and-jboss-as-7)?

```
09:06:06,107 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "gs-serving-web-content-initial.war"
09:06:06,970 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_91]

09:06:06,971 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_91]

09:06:07,142 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/gs-serving-web-content-initial]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@52fd8833, hello.Application@2f8f6d6]
09:06:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 
09:06:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)   .   ____          _            __ _ _
09:06:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
09:06:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
09:06:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
09:06:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
09:06:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
09:06:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.0.RELEASE)
09:06:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 
09:06:08,241 INFO  [hello.Application] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Application on localhost.localdomain with PID 16909 (started by jboss in /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final)
09:06:08,242 INFO  [hello.Application] (MSC service thread 1-2) No profiles are active
09:06:08,456 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@116d77df: startup date [Thu Dec 17 09:06:08 HKT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
09:06:09,278 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-2) Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
09:06:09,537 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
09:06:09,580 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/gs-serving-web-content-initial]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
09:06:09,581 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1126 ms
09:06:10,062 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
09:06:10,063 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
09:06:10,063 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
09:06:10,063 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
09:06:10,063 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
09:06:10,063 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
09:06:10,208 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] (MSC service thread 1-2) Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@116d77df: startup date [Thu Dec 17 09:06:08 HKT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
09:06:10,347 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/greeting]}" onto public java.lang.String hello.GreetingController.greeting(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model)
09:06:10,349 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
09:06:10,349 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
09:06:10,374 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
09:06:10,375 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
09:06:10,451 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
09:06:10,896 INFO  [org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter] (MSC service thread 1-2) Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
09:06:11,231 INFO  [hello.Application] (MSC service thread 1-2) Started Application in 3.996 seconds (JVM running for 78143.668)
09:06:11,235 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /gs-serving-web-content-initial
09:06:11,269 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 4) JBAS018559: Deployed "gs-serving-web-content-initial.war"
```

Comment: did you check if your application is deployed without any errors in the logs?

Comment: JBoss shows the context where the war was deployed. Can you add the log of the deployment ?

Comment: Thanks for the response!! updated to add jboss logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 2 days of investigation / searching I think I would mark my findings here as an answer.

1. Adding a `jboss-web.xml` to the war has some effects, but it has to be in the correct path.

Add the following `jboss-web.xml` to gs-serving-web-content-initial.war\WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
<context-root>myapp</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

JBoss would use the requested context path:

```
09:53:57,523 INFO  [hello.Application] (MSC service thread 1-1) Started Application in 3.192 seconds (JVM running for 167409.96)
09:53:57,541 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /myapp
09:53:57,591 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 7) JBAS018559: Deployed "gs-serving-web-content-initial.war"
```

However this doesn't help the 404 problem at all so the context name shouldn't be the cause.

2. Spring boot application does not work well on JBoss 7.

According to [this article](http://ilya-murzinov.github.io/articles/spring-boot-jboss/), JBoss 7.1.1 Final (I'm also using this) seems to behave strangely on spring boot apps and Spring’s `DispatcherServlet` would `not get instantiated properly`. I guess that's causing the mapping for `/greeting` fails and thus the 404 error.

Conclusion:

The solution in the linked article is too complicated for me to follow, and also doesn't seem to worth to do so since I'm starting a new project instead of migrating. I guess I will abandon Spring Boot and fallback to simple Spring MVC.

Please tell me if I'm missing anything, else I will mark the question answered tomorrow. Thanks all!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with spring boot 1.3.3 app and jboss eap 6.4.x.

Spring boot uses '/' as the default path of the main dispatcher servlet what jboss does not understand correctly (or "too much correctly") and maps servlet dispatcher to '/' instead of '/*', as mentioned in your log:

> 09:06:10,062 INFO 
>   [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean]
>   (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
>   ...

Try to change to something else, for example /xxx or /* using application.properties of your spring boot app:

```
server.servlet-path=/*
```

Now, jboss correctly maps dispatcher servlet to '/xxx/*', resp. '/*'.

Comment: Thx, that helped me a lot.